# [Jersey REST Service]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, websphere, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a web appilcation with Jersey 1.18 + Spring 3.1.0 + Spring data Jpa 1.2.0

I am deploying application on webpshere.Data source is configured through JNDI.

My ear is getting deployed successfully on web sphere,but while hitting button from screen,I get following error in log

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Jersey REST Service]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Any pointers please.

Folllowing is list of dependencies :
Unit.version -> 4.12
springframework.version -> 3.1.0-RELEASE

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javassist</groupId>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
          <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>
        --></dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Spring data jars -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>   
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>  

      <!-- Spring data jars ends -->

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
      </dependencies>


    </dependencyManagement>
```

Following is my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"> 

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.dsa.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Data Source</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Dsa</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Following is my applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dsa.rest" />
    <bean id="clientDetailsService" class="com.dsa.serviceImpl.ClientDetailServiceImpl"/>
    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/Dsa" />

    <!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dsa.dto" />
        <!-- Set share cache mode -->
        <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
        <!-- Set validation mode -->
        <property name="validationMode" value="NONE" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the repository 
        interfaces -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.dsa.repository" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Think you have got the wrong servlet-class configure - try this `<servlet-name>your app name</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>`  Reference - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2065

Comment: Hi Jay....as i am integrating jersey with spring,so I need com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.Actually it was working with Jersey + Spring,but recently I added spring data jpa code as well and I am getting above error,but could not figure out where exactly issue is.

Comment: it seems that your servlet name is an issue. If you are trying to use Spring container then it will try to search with xml configuration in "servletname".xml

Comment: Hi Techbreak...As per my understanding, it should search for servletname.xml if I am using DispatcherServlet,but in  my case I am not using DispatcherServlet..what do u say..

Comment: @user2603985 Can you remove the JPA again to prove that the problem ceases? Seems odd if so, but worth confirming. Also, what version of WebSphere?

Comment: After lot of struggle,got that websphere was not giving exception stack trace correctly.Configured JNDI on tomcat and deployed application.On server start up,I got clear exceptions where it was failing.Updated configuration and dependencies accordingly and I could connect with database.However stragely,If i deploy same code on websphere,still I get exception....to be continued.